# How to return a flag if exist ID in another table mysql

Tags: mysql

i'm try  create a flag that return if exist id from TABLE A on TABLE B example:

```
Table A
------------------
id | name |
 1 | beer |
 2 | wine |
------------------
table B
-----------------
id | id_table_a
1  | 1
```

i would like return some thing like this:

```
-------------------------------
id | name | id_table_a | flag |
 1 | beer | 1          | 1    |
 2 | wine | Null       | 0    |
-------------------------------
```

where flag 1 = exist in another table or 0= dont exist

please a suggest or link !!
Note.- dont have created the row flag maybe exist a posibility create a temporal flag o any suggest...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
select a.*, b.id_table_a, case when b.id is null then 0 else 1 end as flag 
from tablea a
left join tableb b on a.id = b.id_table_a
```

Comment: thanks only have a question why do you use case when b.id ?

Comment: dont is case when b.id_table_a

Comment: you can really use any column of the b table and it will work because all of those columns are null and it doesn't matter if they are included in the select or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.id, CASE WHEN b.id>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END flag
FROM tableA AS a LEFT JOIN tableB AS b ON b.id_table_a=a.id
```

**Edit:** changed the `on`-clause. Thanks @amflare for the hint! The sample data was so short that I overlooked it. :-)

Here's an alternative way:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.id, CAST(COALESCE( b.id, 0) AS BIT) flag
FROM tableA AS a LEFT JOIN tableB AS b ON b.id_table_a=a.id
```

Comment: `ON b.id=a.id` is wrong. You want to join on `b.id_table_a`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, IF(EXISTS(b.id_table_a),(b.id_table_a IS NOT NULL),0) AS flag
FROM TABLEA a
JOIN TABLEB b on a.id = b.id_table_a
```

Something like this should work because the bit in parenthesis will evaluate true/false, and mysql displays true as 1 and false as 0.

Comment: @Tegito123, if it doesn't exist, it should return `0` now